# SQL encoding after restore from backup (mariadb, unix)

Tags: sql, encoding, mariadb

I need to restore a SQL table from daily backup but there are problems with encoding. Backup is made by virtualmin, encoding set to "default". Texts are in French language, so with accents...

Here is the dump of the webmin backup file:
[image]

For the table (wordpress table, interesting fields are:)
[image]

I need to insert a part of this table into the live table (after some deletion of lines..). So the table is already created with

Default collation UTF8mb4_unicode_ci

When I import the table lines into the table, text is not "converted" into the right charset. For example the french "é" shows up as "Ã©". And so on.

I tried a few things, adding SET commands to utf8mb4 before the INSERT, no way, encoding is never done correctly. Text in the base itself shows "Ã©" instead "é", and of course the same when displaying in a browser.

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: How do you import the file? You should tell the importer the encoding of your file (which it seems UTF-8). The file encoding is totally independent to the encoding inside the database (so `UTF8mb4_unicode_ci` doesn't matter much, or better, it just tell you that you can store all UTF-8 characters. So, how do you import the file?

Comment: thed atabse will not convert alone, you have to experiment which collation works maybe general_ci, but are you sure that the original encoding was utf8mb4 doesn't llok that way to me

Comment: I import the file through SQL requests:
INSERT INTO table VALUES etc.

I tried by adding SET NAME = 'utf8mb4' before the INSERT but it didn't help

Comment: Here is an example of text in the file "Le rÃ©seau RTE FranÃ§ais sâapprovisionnera"
I have 100.000 lines with such things and cannot find how to send correctly to DB! Even a text editor (Notepad++) doesn't help to change encoding to show normal text.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.